# Query one table and output data into multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Simply put I am trying to take a single column query result and output it into a 5 wide by × long table. This is how the main table is organized.

[image: Main table]

On separate tabs, I want to list all of the caught and seen Pokemon on their own for easy search. While I can get it to output something like this with

```
=query(NatDex, "Select C Where F <> ''",1)
```

[image: Vertical Table]

I would like it to output the data something like this for easy reading so it's not eventually 100+ entries long:

[image: Horizontal Table]

Bonus points if you can give me formula/something to do it where I can vary how wide the second table is. But this is far less important to me. I've tried looking up stuff like Pivot tables or Transpose, but neither of them seems to have the functions I need to pull this off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you put your query output in some auxiliary column, you can use this formula and drag down:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("A"&6+(ROW()-ROW($A$2))*5&":A")), 1, 5)
```

[image]

---

for 6 columns:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("A"&7+(ROW()-ROW($A$2))*6&":A")), 1, 6)
```

for 3 columns:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("A"&4+(ROW()-ROW($A$2))*3&":A")), 1, 3)
```

for 5 columns but starting on 10th row:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("A"&6+(ROW()-ROW($A$2)-9)*5&":A")), 1, 5)
```

[image]

etc.

Comment: Worked perfectly, and the additional examples really helped show what I needed to change to get things lined up right.