# Google Sheet Split One Column Into Array

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Basically, I have one arbitrarily long column generated from a query gathering data from another sheet. I would like to split this one column into several smaller columns or rows if it's easier, the specifics don't matter only the end goal. 
I think it should be able to be accomplished via some Arrayformula and Array_Constrain wizardry but I just don't know enough about the system to make it do exactly what I want.

I'm using Array_Constrain to make sure anything outside of the given area stops being displayed instead of throwing an error.

[image]

Comment: how this question differs from your previous? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54810583/5632629

Comment: Huh. It's not. I've just been up for 20+ hours and A) Forgot I asked that. and B) Couldn't find it in a search.
Thanks for the help once again.